# Using Python Gitlab API to search for all public repositories

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api, python-gitlab

I want to identify all public repositories in Gitlab with a specific condition. For example, I want to identify all Java projects that has "AndoridManifest.xml" file and contains the word "app" in the repository title or the readme file.

I could do this task with GitHub, but I find it difficult to use the Gitlab search API using python gitlab.

Below is my code

`account = Gitlab('Private token') for item in account.search(gitlab.const.SearchScope.PROJECTS, 'regression', iterator=True):       print(item)`

I expected that I get an iterator that traverses for all open-source (public) repositories in Gitlab. So, I can filter such repositories if they contain the "AndoridManifest.xml"

But I get  **MissingSchema** error. Anyone knows how to solve this error and how I can use python to traverse all Gitlab projects with a specific criteria.